# Retrieve parameters from List using Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

New to Rcpp I am testing how to retrieve and use a nested list from R with a known structure without copying parts of the list again. The small code example (with embedded R code) seems to work (cout is used for debugging).

The list rL retrieved from R may be very big so I do not want to reallocate memory (copy parts of rL). Do the current code copy parts of rL?

Best Lars

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP testing(const List rL) {
   List L(rL);
   SEXP sL2(L["L2"]);
   List L2(sL2);

   SEXP sStateGrpL2(L2["stateGroups"]);
   List stateGrpL2(sStateGrpL2);
   SEXP sStateAllocL2(L2["stateAlloc"]);   
   CharacterVector stateAllocL2(sStateAllocL2);

   SEXP sActionGrpL2(L2["actionGroups"]);
   List actionGrpL2(sActionGrpL2);
   SEXP sActionAllocL2(L2["actionAlloc"]);
   List actionAllocL2(sActionAllocL2);

   vector<string> stateLabels; 
   vector<string> actionLabels;
   CharacterVector actionNames;

   for(int n2 = 0; n2< as<int>(L2["stages"]); n2++) {
      stateLabels = as< vector<string> >(stateGrpL2[as<string>(stateAllocL2[n2])]);
      int s2Size = stateLabels.size(); 
      SEXP sAllocA(actionAllocL2[n2]);
      List allocA(sAllocA);
      actionNames = as<CharacterVector>(allocA[0]);
      cout << "stage:" << n2 << " sN:" << as<string>(stateAllocL2[n2]) << "\n";
      for (int s2=0; s2<s2Size; ++s2) { 
        cout << " s:" << stateLabels[s2] << " aN:" << actionNames[s2] << "\n";
        actionLabels = as< vector<string> >(actionGrpL2[ as<string>(actionNames[s2]) ]);
        int a2Size = actionLabels.size();
        for (int a2=0; a2<a2Size; ++a2) {
           cout << "    a:" << actionLabels[a2] << "\n";
        }
      }
   }

   return wrap(0);
}


/*** R 
L <- list( L2=list(stages=2, 
                   stateGroups=list(s1Grp=c("a","b","c"),s2Grp=c("d","e")), 
                   stateAlloc = c(rep("s1Grp",1),rep("s2Grp",1)), 
                   actionGroups = list(a1Grp=c("terminate","keep"), a2Grp=c("finish")),
                   actionAlloc = list(list( rep("a1Grp",3) ),
                                       list( c("a1Grp","a2Grp") )
                                       )
                   )
     )
testing(L)
*/
```

Comment: Pass by reference `&` if you mean not to alter L ? That said... What are you trying to do?

Comment: rL is a compact representation of the states in a hierarchical Markov decision process. I need C++ since mainly since nested for loops are  very slow in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write:

> The list rL may be very big so I do not want to use new memory (copy
>   parts of rL).  Is this the way to do it?

Pretty much (as far as I can tell from a glance at your code).

All exchange with R uses `SEXP` types where the `P` stands for pointer -- these are shallow proxy objects which will *not be copied*.  It uses / reuses the R object memory.

So if you profile  / memory-profile this it should behave similarly for N=10 and N=1e5.  But the proof is in the pudding...

Comment: Thanks. This was also my guess but I was a bit unsure on how as<> behaves. One more question `List L2(wrap(L["L2"]));` would not be the same since wrap would make a copy?

Comment: But if what you return is an R type (via an Rcpp type) then you may not need wrap.

Answer (score 1):

A few things :

- The loop test `n2< as<int>(L2["stages"])` is both hard to read and
  inefficient as it is calculated at each iteration. You should
  definitely do it just once.
- All of your `as< vector<string> >` create deep copies and does not
  take advantage of the R's string cache. Can't you use a
  `CharacterVector` instead ?

Comment: Off cause I will change the loop. I need a string as input to a function. However, I may change the type to CharacterVector. Thanks